# Right and Replicate in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this line of query in SQL sever and would like to convert it in Oracle. Would someone please provide some pointer?

```
CAR_CD      CAR_YR      CAR_MONTH   CAR_SEQ
LXR          2017          12          1234
```

I would like the outcome like this, using the query below in ORACLE database, not in SQWL.

LXR1712001234

```
CAR_CD + SUBSTRING(CAST(CAR_YR AS VARCHAR(4)),3,2) + CAR_MONTH + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',6) + CAST(CAR_SEQ AS VARCHAR(6)),6)   AS CAR_NUMBER,
```

Comment: If you describe what you are doing, we can provide a better solution than plain translation.

Comment: @ Nayak, I updated my question. Thanks for your comment. Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAR_CD || SUBSTR(CAR_YR,-2) || CAR_MONTH || LPAD(CAR_SEQ,6,'0') FROM yourtable;
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

using http://www.sqlines.com/online

And replace concat operator `+`by `||` :

```
SGTC_CD || 
SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SG_FY(4)),3,2) ||
SG_MONTH || SUBSTR(RPAD('0', LENGTH('0') *6, '0') ||
TO_CHAR(SG_SEQ(6)), 
GREATEST(-LENGTH(RPAD('0', LENGTH('0') *6, '0') ||
TO_CHAR(SG_SEQ AS VARCHAR2(6))),-6))
```

Comment: Oracle doesnot have anything called `Replicate`

Comment: You still have a `+` operator and `TO_CHAR( SG_FY(4) )` and `TO_CHAR(SG_SEQ AS VARCHAR2(6))` are invalid Oracle syntax (also the variables don't match the OP's updated question).

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR` and `LPAD`:

```
SELECT CAR_CD
       || SUBSTR( CAR_YR, -2 )   -- or SUBSTR( CAR_YR, 3, 2 )
       || CAR_MONTH              -- or LPAD( CAR_MONTH, 2, '0' ) for a zero-padded string.
       || LPAD( CAR_SEQ, 6, '0' ) AS Car_number
FROM   your_table
```

However, you would be better converting your year and month columns to a single `DATE` data type then you could do:

```
SELECT CAR_CD
       || TO_CHAR( CAR_YEAR_MONTH_DATE, 'YYMM' ) -- or 'YYFMMM' without leading zero for month 
       || LPAD( CAR_SEQ, 6, '0' ) AS Car_number
FROM   your_table
```

Comment: @MTO, Thanks for your help. This works just perfect. Joe